# Flask table row data to database

Tags: templates, flask

this is my template code:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
            #------Invoice
     #-----Invoice details
            form = InvoiceReportEntries(request.form)
            # items = []
            for item in form.items:
                lineitem = InvoiceLineItem(description=item.description,
                                amount=item.amount,
                                invoice_id=invoice.id)
                db.session.add(lineitem)
                db.session.commit()
```

My template is:

```
<form method="POST">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <table>
                <tr class="heading">
                    <td>
                        Item
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        Price
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="item">
                    <div>
                    <td>
                        <input id={{ items|length }} name="description-{{ items|length }}" required="" type="text" value="">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id={{ items|length }} name="amount-{{ items|length }}" required="" type="text" value="">
                    </td>
                        </div>
                </tr>
```

It seems that my form on submit does not work well as I've this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) float() argument
> must be a string or a number, not 'DecimalField' [SQL: INSERT INTO
> invoice_line_item (description, amount, invoice_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
> [parameters: [{'description': '', 'invoice_id': 14, 'amount':
> <wtforms.fields.core.DecimalField object at 0x10bc52510>}]]

and data form for items are:
{'items': [{'description': '', 'amount': None, 'id': '', 'csrf_token': ''}], 'csrf_token': 'xxxx'}
But I d filled values in my template?
description was 'test' and amount was 23

I will have more Thant one row in this table so I should identified each of them to save them in DB

Thanks for help

UPDATE:
My models :

```
class InvoiceLineItem(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  description = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
  amount = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
  invoice_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('invoice.id'), nullable=False)

  def __init__(self, description, amount, invoice_id):
    self.description = description
    self.amount = amount
    self.invoice_id = invoice_id
```

my forms.py:

```
class InvoiceitemForm(Form):
    description = StringField('Description', validators=[DataRequired()])
    amount = DecimalField('Amount', validators=[DataRequired()])
    id = HiddenField('id')


class InvoiceReportEntries(Form):
    items = FieldList(FormField(InvoiceitemForm), min_entries=1)
```

Comment: Hi, if my solution did not solve the issue , then add the models and the forms to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just I quick advice, so you should've add also the wtforms forms.py and the 'Models.py.'

Hanving sayd that the error you're receiving is quite explicit:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'DecimalField'
```

> What is referring to?

Well as I said I can fully determined why because some snaps of the code is missing, however the error codes speaks by itself:

```
amount': <wtforms.fields.core.DecimalField object at 0x10bc52510>
```

This is because you are calling the Class but not the instance of the class. In fact I guess you have in the forms.py the 'DecimalField', for more info --_> [Here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/).

I can then see the HTML, there isn't the WTFORMS jinja tag but a standar HTML Tag input, this:

```
   <input id={{ items|length }} name="amount-{{ items|length }}" required="" type="text" value="">
```

So I suggest to remove this and add the following:

```
 {{ form.amount.label }}
 {{ form.amount(class='yourclass') }}
```

Instead of the required="", add in the forms.py:

InputRequired() or DataRequired()

- - [InputRequired()](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/#wtforms.validators.InputRequired)
- - [DataRequired()](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/#wtforms.validators.DataRequired)

Comment: Hi Fredrico, I add model and form. could you help ? I will have more than one td in this form, so I will have to get back all items.